# Deleting Note From Array

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

Current I am working on a note app using React.Js and I had the functionality for saving notes but then I decided to add the functionality to remove the note when it is clicked. I wrote some code however, now it won't work. I can't add notes display them. Usually when you click on the button is was suppose to add the note which it was doing before I tried adding the deleting the note functionality. There is also no error in anywhere. I have been trying to solve this the past few days. Here is my code:

[image: App.Js]

[image: CreateNote.Js]

[image: NoteItem.Js]

[image: NoteItem.Js]

Comment: Please add code and not images. That way it is easier for us to debug. If possible **additionally** add a codesandbox link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the id is undefined in your NoteItem component. You are only passing the title to the component. You should pass the note object and then you can have access to the id and title. Suggested changes below:

NotesList

```
const NotesList = (props) => {
    return props.data.map((note) => {

        return (
            <NoteItem 
                note={note}
                key={note.id}
                onDelete={props.onDeleteItem}
            >
            </NoteItem>
        );
    })
}
```

and change NoteItem component to access note as an object. (You could also pass title/id individually as props as well.

NoteItem:

```
const NoteItem = props => {
    const deleteHandler = () => {
        props.onDelete(props.note.id);
    }

    return (
        <h3 onClick={deleteHandler}>{props.note.title}: {props.note.id}</h3>
    )

}
```